# Why do C++ regular expression functions use output parameters?

Tags: c++, regex, output-parameter, cpp-core-guidelines

Output parameters in C++ are generally considered a code smell according to the [core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out). Yet, we have such functions in the [regular expressions library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

```cpp
template< class BidirIt,
          class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits >
bool regex_match( BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
                  std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc>& m,
                  const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& e,
                  std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
                      std::regex_constants::match_default );
```

in which `m` is an output parameter. Is there a specific reason for breaking the core guidelines here and not simply returning the `std::match_results` by value?

Comment: My quick guess: due to `regex_match()` being an overloaded function, with variants not returning a match result at all. Hence a bool was used as a return value.

Comment: The core guidelines don't describe anything as a code smell. In this case, they suggest *preferring* return values over output arguments. That wording does not mean "Thou shalt not ..." - it means "use return values unless you have a particular reason to use output parameters".  The reason, in the case you've picked, is that the function returns more than one type of output to the user - and they've chosen to return `bool` (to indicate if a match is found).  Among other things that avoids forcing the caller to do a relatively expensive check if the set of matches (output parameter) is empty

Answer (score 1):

There are some exceptions too:

- For non-value types, such as types in an inheritance hierarchy, return the object by unique_ptr or shared_ptr.
- **If a type is expensive to move** (e.g., array), consider allocating it on the free store and return a handle (e.g., unique_ptr), or passing it in a reference to non-const target object to fill (to be used as an out-parameter).
- To reuse an object that carries capacity (e.g., std::string, std::vector) across multiple calls to the function in an inner loop: treat it as an in/out parameter and pass by reference.

I think it is the 2nd case for regxr match.